# invalid magic number

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I want to install the Ubuntu Kylin 13.04 on a pre-installed win8 system.
I follow the [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

But when I choose to install the Ubuntu Kylin through grub, I get errors.

```
error: invalid magic number.

error: please load the kernel first.
```

I install by live USB.And i use Linux live USB creator.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by changing a new USB drive. It seems there is some problem with my former USB drive